# why do i get a Parse input error in haskell

Tags: haskell

I get a parse input error and 'e'. Why is this? Fixed my indentations too

```
if not(true)
    then do g
            Node value e
    else return()
where
    f = false
    g = if f then Map.delete c children 
    e = Map.insert c (Node Nothing children) children
```

Comment: You seem to be confused about `insert` and `delete` from (I assume) `Data.Map`. They are not actions that modify an existing map in place; they are functions that return a *new* map with a given key–value pair added or removed, respectively. (The new map is not a complete copy—it shares most of its memory with the old one.)

Comment: I wonder what's behind the magic in `not (true)`

Answer (score 4):

`else` branch in the definition of `g` should also be covered.

Answer (score 3):

You're getting a parse error because the parser is expecting to see the `else` part of the `if` on the previous line - not another variable definition. Every `if` needs an `else` in Haskell  - otherwise what would the value of `g` be when `f` is false?

Once you've fixed that problem, you'll get a type error in your `do` statement for two reasons: The values in your `do` statement aren't monadic (`g` is a `Map` and `Node value e` is whichever type defines the `Node` constructor); and the types of your `then` and `else` don't match: The else part has type `m ()` for some `Monad m` and the `then` part has whichever type `Node` is part of.